# Extracting single words from entries with multiple words from a column in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with multiple columns which has a column named categories. Each entry in a column is consisted of multiple words. Each row has a different number of words. How can I create another table with one column in which each entry would be a single word from the categories column from the previous table?

The table i have and the column i would like to target:

- categories

  1. Golf, Active Life
  2. Specialty Food, Restaurants, Dim Sum, Imported Food, Food, Chinese, Ethnic Food, Seafood

I would like another table with one column:

- categories

  1. Golf
  2. Active Life
  3. Specialty Food
  4. Restaurants
  5. Dim Sum
  6. ...

EDIT: For anyone in the future, I needed a permanent table. Check the comments for full answer.

Comment: Stop storing comma separated records within a single column. It is bound to cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's easy to implement this in PG, just use `string_to_array` and `unnest` function, like below:

```
select
    unnest(string_to_array(categories,',')) as word
into my_new_table
from
    table
```

The example as below:

```
select unnest(string_to_array('Specialty Food, Restaurants, Dim Sum, Imported Food, Food, Chinese, Ethnic Food',','));
     unnest     
----------------
 Specialty Food
  Restaurants
  Dim Sum
  Imported Food
  Food
  Chinese
  Ethnic Food
(7 rows)
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It was very useful but I actually wanted a permanent table created, not just data selected from another table. The full answer would be:
CREATE TABLE table_name AS SELECT unnest(string_to_array(column_name, ',')) AS name_for_new_table FROM table_from_which_the_new_table_is_created;

Thank you @Shawn.X, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @AsadSehic OK, edited above, use `into table` directly. you would get a new table easily.

Comment: I did it a bit differently, but both answers work. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations!